# Quasi-periodic motion of $N$-particle systems

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, second-quantization

My question is about the time evolution of multi-particle systems in QFT. There are such systems evolving a-periodically. I struggle with the treatment of them, always obtaining periodic or quasi-periodic solutions.

For example consider two hypothetical chemicals, a and b, interacting according to the reaction equation a + b =2a. Under idealized conditions the concentrations evolve according to the ODEs da/dt = ab and db/dt = -ab. If initially ab<>0, then d(ln a)/dt > 0, so a grows following a hyperbolic tangent curve until b vanishes.

Notice that the reaction equations are time-independent.

Problem: Find a time-independent Hamiltonian such that the number operator N_a of a evolves in the same way.

If you can provide a solution in the same abstract setting (not an example from physics for a specific kind of real particles), then you may stop here. Otherwise you may review my considerations below.

Let A be an observable with m eigenvalues. E.g. m=2 for the spin. Let's denote particles of different A-values as different particle types. E.g. in chemistry, the particles are molecules, and one may study a system of m types of molecules.

Let's assume that interactions of particles of different types yield particles of other types. This is e.g. the case in chemistry, where the interactions are described by reaction equations.

In a closed system of N particles of m types the evolution of the number of particles of each type is of interest. E.g. in chemistry, the evolution of the concentrations of the various chemicals, under idealized conditions, is completely determined by the reaction equations and reaction constants.

Let's assume that, under suitable conditions, the evolution of the observable A is completely determined by interaction equations (like chemical reaction equations) in terms of the m particle types, like in the chemical example.

The interaction equations are easily translated into products of creation and annihilation operators. Let's assume conservation of the total particle number. so creation and annihilation operators are paired.

Assume that only interactions of up to k particles do occur.

Under these preliminaries, I wish to establish the Hamiltonian H for an N-particle system, where m and k are constants, N arbitrary but finite.

H is a sum of interaction terms up to order k. The number of terms depends on k and m and is finite.

H operates on state vectors in Fock space representation. For fixed N, the state vectors span a sub-space of Fock space of O(N^m) dimension.

The restriction of H to this sub-space is a finite-dimensional matrix, M. For fixed N, M determines the time evolution of the system.

If M is Hermitian, then it has finitely many real eigenvalues and finitely many eigenvectors. Therefore the evolution is (at least) quasi-periodic, thus returning close to the initial state at infinitely many times.

However, this is not the case, generally. Why? Is M not Hermitian? Is there a mistake in the derivation? Or in the problem statement?

Comment: You might want to look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction

Comment: what exactly is $m$ here? In general your Hamiltonian $H''$ need not be finite dimensional

Comment: m is the number of particle states. E.g. m=2 when considering the spin states, or m= 5 when considering interacting particles of five kinds.